# Local TaskBar Over Remote

Tags: c, windows, taskbar

I have an issue I want to debug. On Superuser the question has more details about my issue:

https://superuser.com/questions/1243000/local-taskbar-visible-during-remote-desktop-fullscreen

Killing explorer.exe works but after 30 minutes later or so it comes back. I have killed off all of my notification icons but so far I had no luck to find the bad guy who wants to send me a notification.
The answer tells me that an application has set in explorer the **MustBeSeen** flag which added to Windows 10 some time ago.

My question is which C/COM API is used to set this flag?

I want to intercept that call in a debugger and find the bad guy which is forcing the taskbar of my local machine to overlay the remote one.